# Preforming set theory between a xmltype column and a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype, set-theory

I am working with an oracle db on a legacy application and having trouble coming up with a specific query for it.

Basically I have one table T_Selected with a number column(primary key) and an xmltype column.
The XML is of the format

```
<countries>
    <country>England</country>
    <country>Ireland</country>
    <country>Scotland</country>
    <country>Wales</country>
</countries>
```

I also have another table that I need to query and use the result

```
select country from T_Countries where language = 'English'
```

I need three queries and their negatives.

> 1. All the countries in the xml ∈ subquery
> 2. Subquery ∈ All the countries in the xml
> 3. All the countries in the xml = to all the subquery

The closest I have gotten is

```
select id from 
        T_Selected ts, 
        XMLTABLE('/countries/country'                  
                 passing ts.Values        
                 columns                                     
                 Country  path '//country'
                ) XML
        where XML.country in (select country from T_Countries 
                                                  where language ='English');
```

This will return ids where any of the xml countries are in the sub-query, rather than all of them.

Any ideas on how I might go about this?

Thanks for the help,

Niall

Answer (score 0):

1. XML subset of SUB
   select id
   from
   (select id
   from
       T_Selected ts,
       XMLTABLE('/countries/country'
                passing ts.Values
                columns
                Country  path '//country'
               ) XML) xml
   RIGHT OUTER join (select country from T_Countries
                                                 where language ='English') SUB) SUB on SUB.country=xml.country
   where XML.country is not null;
2. SUB subset of XML
   select  xml.id
   from
   (select id from
       T_Selected ts,
       XMLTABLE('/countries/country'
                passing ts.Values
                columns
                Country  path '//country'
               ) XML) q1
   LEFT OUTER join (select country from T_Countries
                                                 where language ='English') SUB on SUB.country=xml.country   ) q2 on q2.country=q1.country
   where q2.countyid is not null;
3. UNION XML and SUB
   select id, country from
       T_Selected ts,
       XMLTABLE('/countries/country'
                passing ts.Values
                columns
                Country  path '//country'
               ) XML
   UNION ALL
   select id, country from T_Countries
                                                 where language ='English') SUB on SUB.country=xml.country
   ;

Comment: Hi Ed, Thanks for the response. The queries are still not quite right as select id from T_Selected ts, XMLTABLE('/countries/country' passing ts.Values columns Country path '//country' ) returns a row for each of the countries. This makes the result hold values where any of the countries are in the subquery, rather than all of them.